# Why is this true: $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}/\langle\alpha\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}\rangle\cong\langle\alpha, \beta:\alpha\beta=\beta^{-1}\alpha\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can one explain to me why is this true?
$$\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}/\langle\alpha \beta \alpha \beta^{-1}\rangle \cong \langle\alpha, \beta: \alpha \beta =  \beta^{-1} \alpha\rangle$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$\langle\alpha,\beta\mid\alpha\beta=\beta^{-1}\alpha\rangle\cong\langle\alpha,\beta\mid\beta\alpha=\alpha^{-1}\beta\rangle,$$ and that $$\beta\alpha=\alpha^{-1}\beta$$ if and only if $$\alpha\beta\alpha=\beta$$ if and only if $$\alpha\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}=e.$$ Can you get the rest of the way?

Comment: thanks a lot, i think i can get the rest thank u :)

Comment: But what if I want use the first isomorphism theorem? I was trying the homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ by $\phi (\alpha^{k_1} \beta^{k_2}\alpha^{k_3} \beta^{k_4} ... \alpha^{k_{n-3}} \beta^{k_{n-2}}\alpha^{k_{n-1}} \beta^{n}) = \alpha \beta \alpha \beta^{-1}...\alpha \beta \alpha \beta^{-1}$ but i think it is not useful! what do you think?

Comment: No, that's definitely not useful. The big thing to keep in mind, here, is that $$\Bbb Z_\alpha*\Bbb Z_\beta/\langle\alpha\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}\rangle=\langle\alpha,\beta\mid\alpha \beta\alpha\beta^{-1}=e\rangle.$$ That's just what the $\langle\text{generators}\mid\text{relations}\rangle$ notation means.

Comment: Instead, take the isomorphism $\Bbb Z_\alpha*\Bbb Z_\beta\to\Bbb Z_\alpha*\Bbb Z_\beta$ given by $\alpha\mapsto\beta,\beta\mapsto\alpha.$ Then compose it with the canonical projection $\Bbb Z_\alpha*\Bbb Z_\beta\to\Bbb Z_\alpha*\Bbb Z_\beta/ \langle\beta\alpha\beta\alpha^{-1}\rangle.$ (cont'd)

Comment: This is readily seen to be a surjective homomorphism with kernel $\langle\alpha\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}\rangle,$ and since $$\begin{align}\Bbb Z_\alpha*\Bbb Z_\beta/\langle\beta\alpha\beta\alpha^{-1}\rangle &= \langle\alpha,\beta\mid\beta\alpha\beta\alpha^{-1}=e\rangle\\ &= \langle\alpha,\beta\mid\beta\alpha\beta=\alpha\rangle\\ &= \langle\alpha,\beta\mid\alpha\beta=\beta^{-1}\alpha\rangle,\end{align}$$ we're done. This is the approach that I was describing in my answer, incidentally.

Comment: this is very nice,, thank you so much :)

Comment: One question (which really should have occurred to me earlier): By $\langle\alpha\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}\rangle$, do you mean the [normal closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_closure_(group_theory)) of $\{\alpha\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}\}$, or do you mean the [cyclic subgroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_subgroup) generated by $\alpha\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}$? This notation is more typically used to indicate the latter, but the former--usually denoted $\langle\alpha\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}\rangle^{\Bbb Z*\Bbb Z}$--is what we need in order to make the result (and my claims) true.

Comment: @ Cameron Buie: it is the subgroup generated by $\langle\{\alpha\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}\}\rangle$

Comment: The *cyclic* subgroup, or the *normal* subgroup?

Comment: ok, it is normal (by Van Kampen theorem) and it is obviously (i think) cyclic

Comment: Note that $$\beta^{-1}(\alpha\beta\alpha\beta^{-1})\beta=\beta^{-1}\alpha\beta\alpha$$ is not an element of the cyclic subgroup generated by $\alpha\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}$, so that one can't be normal. It must be intended to represent the normal subgroup generated by $\alpha\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}$, then. Excellent! That means that I didn't tell you a bunch of wrong stuff!